# Better way to achieve filtering data in dplyr

Tags: r, analytics, data-analysis

I have feedback data about Immigration.Services, its many rows, each row having a value ("satisfied","Very satisfied"..)  and country name. I want to group by first to get number of countries having more than 1 row, then I want to get count of "satisfied" , "distaisfied" ... per country but only for countries with more than feedback row. I achieved it as below code, but this has a it of duplication, is there a better way to achieve this?

```
c <- subset(fd, !is.na(Immigration.Services)  ) %>%
group_by(Origin.Country)  %>%
tally() %>%
filter(n>1)  %>%
select(Origin.Country)

#code to select data for countries required
subset(fd, !is.na(Immigration.Services)  ) %>%
group_by(Origin.Country,Immigration.Services)  %>%
tally() %>%
filter(Origin.Country %in% c[["Origin.Country"]])
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some sample data and the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c <- subset(fd, !is.na(Immigration.Services)  ) %>%
group_by(Origin.Country)  %>%
tally() %>%
filter(n>1)  %>%
group_by(Origin.Country,Immigration.Services)  %>%
tally()
```

Does this improve things?